# cannot read manifest file when running Maven Java project through Main class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, manifest

I have a java project having Multi module maven project structure. 
When project is built, Jar is created successfully and it executes properly when run through command line and reads the manifest file wherein fields like:
Implementation-Vendor, Implementation-Title, Implementation-Version are added.

But when I try to run same project from eclipse (Right-click on Main class --> Select Run As --> Java Application), project starts successfully but cannot read manifest file as the above said parameter are not found and set to null runtime.

I read the manifest using Package.getPackage() method.
Like for example : String title = someClass.getPackage().getImplementationTitle()

Can any one tell how to read manifest file when running java application through eclipse.